# exception in java

Tags: exception

private String getEmailTemplateWithActualValueForAccount(String template, Account account) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    List<String> listTags = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<Method, String> methodList = new HashMap<Method, String>();

    int startIndex=0;
    int endIndex=0;

    for(int i=0; i<template.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = template.charAt(i);
        if(ch=='$')
            startIndex = i+1;
        if(ch=='#')
        {
            endIndex = i+1;
            listTags.add(template.substring(startIndex,endIndex));
        }

    }

    Method[] methods = Account.class.getMethods();

    for (Method method : methods) {
        String methodName = method.getName();
        if(method.getName().startsWith("get"))
        {
            methodList.put(method, methodName.substring(3,methodName.length()).toUpperCase()+"#");
        }
    }

    Set<Method> methodKeySet = methodList.keySet();
    for (Method method : methodKeySet) {
        for (String string : listTags) {

            if(methodList.get(method).equals(string))
            {
                try{
                    Object obj = method.invoke(account, null);
                    if(obj!=null)
                        map.put(string, obj.toString());
                }catch(NullPointerException e){
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    final StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder( "\\$(" );
    for( final String key: map.keySet() )
    { 
        list.append( key ); 
        list.append( "|" ); 
    }
    list.append( "[^\\s\\S])" );
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( list.toString() );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( template );


    final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while( matcher.find() ){
        final String string = matcher.group( 1 );
        matcher.appendReplacement( stringBuffer, map.get( string )); 
    }
    matcher.appendTail( stringBuffer );

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

I got an exception at line of code "Object obj = method.invoke(account, null);"
Code is perfectly working but as this code is in scheduler it will create an log at every 20 second on jboss server.

Comment: You'll get better response if you add context to your question. Do you have code that is throwing it? If so post it. Are you worried about catching it? If so, what methods throw it that you're concerned about?

Comment: Could you provide your code that is throwing this exception?

Comment: ... so the code is NOT perfectly working, right? Just because a code compiles, doesn't make it work exactly the way you wanted it to. Obviously in this case it doesn't, so it's not, in fact, "perfectly working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invoke method of Method throws an InvocationTargetException "if the underlying method throws an exception", according to the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29). So you better look into the method that you are invoking to find out why it's throwing an exception. Check the exception stack trace for the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching `NullPointerException`, you should catch `InvocationTargetException`, and check the wrapped exception.